# Equivalence of Büchi automata and linear $\mu$-calculus

Tags: logic, automata, formal-methods, linear-temporal-logic, buchi-automata

It's a known fact that every LTL formula can be expressed by a Büchi $\omega$-automaton. But, apparently, Büchi automata are a more powerful, expressive model. I've heard somewhere that Büchi automata are equivalent to linear-time $\mu$-calculus (that is, $\mu$-calculus with usual fixpoints and only one temporal operator: $\mathbf{X}$).

Is there an algorithm (constructive proof) of this equality?

Comment: I do not know too much about logics. NBA are equivalent to MSO, afaik; do you know something about the relation of MSO and your logic?

Comment: @Raphael unfortunately, I don't know much about MSO

Comment: Note that regular languages, DFA, NFA and NBA are equivalent over **MSO over strings**, but not "equivalent" to MSO in a general sense (over arbitrary structures). Actually, second-order logic (SO), when considered over strings, is also equivalent to monadic second-order logic (MSO), but SO in general is much more expressive than LTL.

Comment: REG, DFA and NFA correspond to WMSO, not MSO.

Comment: @Raphael the equivalence is valid for MSO (finite words and $\omega$-words). See [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.19.805) and [here](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/06/06/08/PDF/LogicOnWords.pdf), for example.

Comment: Well, ok; an MSO formula that discribes a language with only finite words *is* a WMSO formula, right? Because I learned the WMSO characterisation.

Comment: Apparently, NBA is equivalent to $\omega$-regular languages and LTL (over infinite strings) is equivalent to star-free $\omega$-regular languages.

Comment: @Daniil: What does "star-free" mean here?

Comment: Over transition systems, several flavors of $\mu$-calculus seem to be contained in MSO and contain (at least) a notable subset of MSO [[JaWa1996](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-61604-7_60),[Rohde2002](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/3-540-36387-4_14)].

Comment: @Raphael "star-free" means having a star height of zero. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star-free_language . Thanks for the links, I'll check out them later.

Comment: @Daniil: That definition is "made" for languages finite words. How does is apply to $\omega$-languages? $\omega$ is allowed but $*$ is not?

Comment: @Raphael, basically star-free languages with $\omega$ are equivalent to LTL over both finite and infinite words, I believe. Star-free languages over an alphabet $\Sigma$ is the smallest set containing $\Sigma^{\infty}$, all singletons and is closed under finite union, concatenation and complementation.

Comment: @Raphael http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/06/06/08/PDF/LogicOnWords.pdf - this article was a good starting point for me, although I myself is no expert and have yet to fully understand the algebraic and automata methods for $\omega$-languages.

Answer (score 18):

The constructive equivalence of linear-time fixed point formulae (the logic is called $\nu$TL by some) and Buechi automata is given in a paper by Mads Dam from 1992.

> [Fixed Points of Buchi Automata](http://www.imit.kth.se/%7Emfd/Papers/fba.ps), FST&TCS 1992.

See page 4 for the construction of a $\nu$TL formula from a Buechi automaton. The construction of a Buechi automaton from a $\nu$TL formula is more complicated and takes the rest of the paper.

The rest of this reply is a brief argument that this result existed in the literature in far less direct form. Pierre Wolper showed that there were omega-regular properties that were not LTL-definable and gave an extension of LTL (called ETL) that could express omega-regular properties.

> [Temporal Logic can be more expressive](http://www.sable.mcgill.ca/abc/archives/private/2006-Apr/att.../wolper.pdf), Pierre Wolper, Information and Computation, 1983.

It is also known that one can translate ETL formulae into $\nu$TL formulae, so by combining these results you can read off a translation of Buechi automata into $\nu$TL. In the other direction, it follows from the work of Buechi that S1S (the second order theory of one successor) formulae can be compiled into Buechi automata and by translating $\nu$TL formulae into S1S, we obtain a translation of $\nu$TL to Buechi automata.
If you want a more in-depth introduction to these topics, I suggest Mads Dam's lecture notes, or the work of Roope Kaivola (sadly not as widely known as much related work).

> [Temporal Logics, Automata, and Classical Theories - An Introduction](http://www.imit.kth.se/%7Emfd/Papers/fba.ps), Mads Dam, ESSLLI 1994.
>
> [Using Automata to Characterise Fixed Point Temporal Logics](http://www.lfcs.inf.ed.ac.uk/reports/97/ECS-LFCS-97-356/index.html), Roope Kaivola

Comment: Is there a result for the OP's question in these references, or is it open?

Comment: I have clarified my answer.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, there was a similar problem in [Moshe Vardi](http://www.cs.rice.edu/~vardi/)'s talk at the [Fields Institute](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca) (it wasn't about $\mu$-calculus though).

You may want to check [the slides](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/audio/11-12/CLS_constraint/vardi3/index.html?1;large#slideloc) or check Vardi's papers. There is definitely an algorithm but IIRC the negations cause a [huge increase in the time](http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/audio/11-12/CLS_constraint/vardi3/index.html?14;large#slideloc) required to perform the translation.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to be complete.

Comment: @Dave, yes, it isn't.